# WebStorm, how do I mv lots of file and refactor at the same time?

Tags: intellij-idea, pycharm, ide, webstorm

I have a folder with mixed, .png's and .svg's. There are hundreds of them all mixed together. Now I tried `mv *.png ./png && mv *.svg ./svg`, the issue with this is, it doesn't refactor. YIKES.

I tied moving one at a time but that is not optimal at all. Is there a way to move a batch of files from one folder to another in WebStorm so that it also refactors?

Comment: You can only use IDE refactorings, which are initiated from the IDE interface. It will not work from the command line. So you have to select all needed files and move.

Comment: You can use "Find/Replace in Files" -- just a plain "Find & Replace" that works on multiple files (folders), supports RegEx. https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/finding-and-replacing-text-in-project.html . Might require more than approach (depends on how you were referencing those images in your code). BTW: by default the IDE should highlight broken references to files from HTML/CSS code.

Comment: Thanks guys, thats kinda what i figured.